# Google Chrome - always openning as a Karma window

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, karma-jasmine, ubuntu-16.04

So the funny moment.

I tested my app and ran tests on `Karma + Jasmine` before commit with `Husky` tool. Once Chrome got stuck and after reboot system Chrome always opens as a new Karma window in incognito mode. The Chrome icon is renamed too.

[image]

[image]

I tried to reinstall Chrome but issue still exists. I have:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

So I can I revert changes and get back my lovely Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Karma has configurations in `~/.local/share/applicaitons`. It lock the Chrome and creates a `karma-<random-numbers>` test kit in `tmp` folder.

To fix it

```
cd ~/.local/share/applicaitons
rm google-chrome.desktop
```